# ApiInformation check for StoreRequestHelper.SendRequestAsync()

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm using `SendRequestAsync()`, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storerequesthelper.sendrequestasync#Windows_Services_Store_StoreRequestHelper_SendRequestAsync_Windows_Services_Store_StoreContext_System_UInt32_System_String_), more specifically the request code `16` documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/request-ratings-and-reviews#show-a-rating-and-review-dialog-in-your-app), to show a review dialog in my app.
My code is essentially the one of the example and it's working fine on my system.

From documentation it says that

> The SendRequestAsync method is available only to apps that target Windows 10, version 1607, or later. Some of the requests supported by this method are only supported in releases after Windows 10, version 1607.

And no info about the request code `16` seems to indicate that it requires a build later than `1607`.

My objective now is to add a check via `ApiInformation` to use this method only from supported Windows 10 builds, otherwise use [this uglier solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/request-ratings-and-reviews#launch-the-rating-and-review-page-for-your-app-in-the-store) which launches the Store app.

I've tried with the following

```
if(ApiInformation.IsMethodPresent(nameof(StoreRequestHelper), nameof(StoreRequestHelper.SendRequestAsync)))
{
     //use StoreRequestHelper.SendRequestAsync()
}
else
{
     //Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()
}
```

However the check returns false even on my system, which is on the latest build and can open the dialog if the check is removed.

What is the correct way to check for this API?

Answer (score 0):

The issue resulted being about the way I obtained the name of the class, which needs to have the full namespace path. In fact `nameof` only returns the name of the class:
`nameof(StoreRequestHelper) -> "StoreRequestHelper"`. To obtain the correct name I used `typeof(StoreRequestHelper).FullName`.

The working code is thus:

```
if(ApiInformation.IsMethodPresent(typeof(StoreRequestHelper).FullName, nameof(StoreRequestHelper.SendRequestAsync), 3))
{
     //use StoreRequestHelper.SendRequestAsync()
}
else
{
     //Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()
}
```